# Bottom up CSS animation of svg element

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Is there a pure CSS way to animate SVG rect element appearing bottom up, but from a certain point, not from the parents bottom?

For example, let's say that I have a `<rect>` elements that lies on an axis, and that I want it to expand from the axis up:

```css
rect {
  fill: lightgreen;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 2;
  animation: expand 0.75s ease;

  /* transform-origin: top bottom; */
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

text {
  font: italic 20px serif;
  fill: gray;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200px" width="100px">
  <rect x="5" y="50" height="100" width="50"></rect>
  <line x1="5" y1="150" x2="90" y2="150"></line>
  <text x="5" y="170">axis</text>
</svg>
```

As shown in examples, it expands from the parents bottom (because of the `transform-origin` attribute). Is there a pure CSS way to expand it from the axis, without changing the `<svg>` size? What would be JS alternative (but without jQuery)?

Comment: `transform-box: fill-box;` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you! Didn't know about this property. When I add `transform-box: fill-box;` to `rect` style, it start animation from the bottom of the rect element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `translateY` to your transform, using half the height of the rectangle as a beginning offset.

```css
rect {
  fill: lightgreen;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 2;
  animation: expand 0.75s ease;

  /* transform-origin: top bottom; */
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px) scaleY(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px) scaleY(1);
  }
}

line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

text {
  font: italic 20px serif;
  fill: gray;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200px" width="100px">
  <rect x="5" y="50" height="100" width="50"></rect>
  <line x1="5" y1="150" x2="90" y2="150"></line>
  <text x="5" y="170">axis</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I solved the issue with `transform-box: fill-box;` as suggested by @TermaniAfif

Comment: I couldn't use `translateY(-50px)` because the size of SVG is dependent on the size of its parent, so I wouldn't know how much I need to translate in advanced. I'd have to use JS/TS to determine that. Thank you :)

Comment: @Liliane Glad you solved it. Just be aware of the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box#Browser_compatibility) for `transform-box`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Those darn IE and Edge >:(